# How can I discover why a given HTTP request failed?

Tags: c#

I want to discover what causes a link to not work. Instead of not working, the link should show a particular message, like 404 or 403. How can I discover what HTTP status caused a given request to fail?

```
if (!IsLinkWorking(link))
{
     //Here you can show the error. You don't specify how you want to show it.
     TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green; 
     TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\nNot working\n\n ", link);
}
else
{
     TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\n working\n\n", link);
}
```

Comment: You need to, at the very least, include the code you have for IsLinkWorking.

Comment: i have one textbox which contain url and i am sending webrequest to that url and in the result i wan error message ins-ted of link not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an HttpWebRequest. This will return you an HttpWebResponse, that has a StatusCode property - [see the documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx).

Here is an example:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    TextBox2.Text = "HTTP Response is: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons for not working links, you can try `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse` with proper HTTP header values to check whether link works or not.

Note that in case of 403, 404 etc. errors it throws exception which you should handle or else it will not give you the response status:

```
try{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    /* Set HTTP header values */
    request.Method = "MethodYouWantToUse"; // GET, POST etc.
    request.UserAgent = "SomeUserAgent";
    // Other header values here...

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
    TextBox2.Text = "HTTP Response is: {0}", response.StatusDescription);

}
catch(WebException wex){
    if(wex.Response != null){
        HttpWebResponse response = wex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                TextBox2.Text = "HTTP Response is: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
            }            
    }
}
```